# Refresh LinkedIn token with omniauth before expiration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omniauth, linkedin-api

I have a Rails (3.2.11) application that allows users to post updates to their LinkedIn profiles.  I'm currently using the `omniauth-linkedin` gem to capture the initial user authentication and the `linkedin` gem to post the updates.  The problem I'm having is that LinkedIn access tokens expire after 60 days, but according to their [documentation](http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/authentication#handling) a token can be refreshed prior to expiration without a user having to reauthorize the application.

I've looked at the LinkedIn [Tips and Tricks](https://developer.linkedin.com/blog/tips-and-tricks-refreshing-access-token), [Authentication Overview](http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/authentication), and tons of posts on StackOverflow - [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13586713/refresh-linkedin-user-access-token-without-user-intervention), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13411938/linkedin-api-how-to-refresh-access-tokens-from-a-console-application), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8858082/linkedin-grant-access-screen-showing-even-though-user-already-authenticated) being just a couple of examples - and I still can't find any answers.

After a user authorizes the app (via `omniauth-linkedin`), I save the `access_token` and `secret` returned to me from LinkedIn.  I need to figure out how I can use the still-valid `access_token` to refresh it and extend the expiration date another 60 days.

I've tried using the authenticate endpoint from LinkedIn (where `tokens.access_token` is the currently valid token):

```
url = "https//www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/authenticate?oauth_token=" + tokens.access_token
result = RestClient.post(url, {oauth_callback: "http://localhost:3000/users/auth/linkedin/callback"})
```

but I get an `undefined method 'request_uri' for #<URI::Generic:0x1b144d20>` Exception.

I've tried using the OAuth::Consumer client (where `tokens.access_token` and `tokens.token_secret` are the currently valid tokens):

```
configuration = { site: 'https://api.linkedin.com', authorize_path: '/uas/oauth/authenticate',
                  request_token_path: '/uas/oauth/requestToken', access_token_path: '/uas/oauth/accessToken' }
consumer = OAuth::Consumer.new(ENV['LINKEDIN_APP_ID'], ENV['LINKEDIN_SECRET'], configuration)
access_token = OAuth::AccessToken.new(consumer, tokens.access_token, tokens.token_secret)
```

but this just gives me back the same `access_token` and `secret`.

In the end, I'd love to be able to leverage the existing `omniauth-linkedin` gem functionality to handle this refresh, any idea if this is possible?  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

In your second approach (using the OAuth::Consumer client and passing in your existing access token and secret) should refresh the token for you. As the documentation states, as long as the current user is logged into LinkedIn.com and the current access token hasn't expired yet, the token will be refreshed.

That doesn't mean necessarily that you'll get a new token. You may get the same one as you had before. The key difference is that the lifespan of the token should 60 days. You can verify this by check the value of **oauth_expires_in** parameter. It should be set to 5184000.

This blog post goes into detail about refreshing the token: https://developer.linkedin.com/blog/tips-and-tricks-refreshing-access-token

Comment: I tried this same approach and it returned the same token and secret that I passed in, however the `params` are empty, so I can't verify if my token's expiration date was reset to 60 days from now.